# PayPal Buy Now button on my site with redirection issue

Tags: paypal, content-management-system, paypal-ipn

I must be going crazy, or I'm completely lost when it comes to understanding what is doable when it comes to PayPal buttons on my site - either way I must apologise if this seems obtuse.

I'm building a custom CMS for my clients, and I'm trying to let them utilize PayPal on their sites by simply entering in either their merchant ID, or their PayPal e-mail address, and then let CMS will do the rest. Ideally:

- Client enters merchant ID / PayPal e-mail address into CMS backend
- CMS generates "Buy Now" button for client's buyers to click on
- Buyer pays on PayPal's site
- Buyer gets redirected to client's site
- My headache disappears

This seems to be easier said than done. I've read the developer documentation on [generating your own buttons](http://paypal.github.io/JavaScriptButtons/), and used that Javascript-based button generator to create a button with an IPN callback, but that's not going to redirect the buyers back to my clients' websites.

Thus my questions: is it at all possible to achieve what I'm looking to do with just my clients' merchant ID's? Is it possible to do it without them having to configure anything additional in their PayPal account settings to avoid set-up issues? Should I be looking at a different PayPal processing mechanism instead of the "Buy Now" button?

I should probably mention that I have a free PayPal account, not a Premium or Business account, but that should be irrelevant to this situation as it's not me that's trying to get paid.

Thanks in advance, and any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A thank you to Billy for his answer, and while researching this topic some more, I've discovered that what I'm looking to do CANNOT be done with the current payment standards buttons on a standard free PayPal account. You can't achieve automatic redirection back to your site from PayPal with the Buy Now button.

As Billy mentioned, you can add return URLs that will give the user the option to click on a link that will return them to your site afterwards (PayPal will add these links to their side of operations themselves). To do this you would need to add the appropriate hidden fields to your PayPal form.

This worked for me:

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
    <input type="hidden" name="button" value="buynow">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Item 1">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1234.56">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="env" value="www">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.site.com/success">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.site.com/error">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="your@email.com">
</form>
```

I hope this helps someone avoid headache and unnecessary documentation scouring!

Answer (score 1):

create a hidden field named 'return' in your form and put your return URL as the 'value'

Comment: Thank you for answering! I've figured out what I needed to based on your input...check out my answer if you like! Thanks again! :)